# Multiple Sliding Window on a single Data Stream

Tags: apache-flink, sliding-window

I am currently working on a problem in Flink, wherein I'll have to compute aggregate functions for three different sliding windows of window sizes 7 days,14 days and 1 month. 
From what I've understood I'd have to run three different consumers parallelly having the above mentioned window sizes. Is there a way to implement three sliding windows for a single data stream all using a single consumer code?
Some code or reference to implement this using Flink is very appreciable.

What I know :
consumer 1 computes over a sliding window of size 7 days
consumer 2 computes over a sliding window of size 14 days
and so on.
What I want:
**consumer 1 computing all these sliding windows simultaneously for a single data stream**.

*Is it possible to implement this in Flink?*

Comment: Why do you want to process all the windows together in a single operator?

Comment: I have one stream of data and need to perform many operations on that. I would like to find popular in the last day, last week etc.. What is the correct way to do all these with one stream?

Answer (score 2):

The various windows can share a single stream produced by one kafka consumer, like this:

```
consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("topic", new topicSchema(), kafkaProps);
stream = env.addSource(consumer);

w1 = stream.keyBy(key)
  .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(7), Time.days(1))
  .process(...)

w2 = stream.keyBy(key)
  .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(14), Time.days(1))
  .process(...)
```

Or to be more efficient, you might structure it like this:

```
consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("topic", new topicSchema(), kafkaProps);
stream = env.addSource(consumer);

dayByDay = stream.keyBy(key)
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1))
  .process(...)

w1 = dayByDay.keyBy(key)
  .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(7), Time.days(1))
  .process(...)

w2 = dayByDay.keyBy(key)
  .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(14), Time.days(1))
  .process(...)
```

Note, however, that there is no Time.months(), so if you want windows aligned to month boundaries, I guess you'll have to figure that part out.